# The name of the custom list for "Detected in Cycle" field in QC

Tags: custom-lists

I am tring to extract the possible values available in QC defects section for "Detected in Cycle" field.

I tried doing it for "Defects status", i was able to extract the values Resolved, Open, Assigned....

The code which i tried for extracting status values is as below:

```
Set cust = QCConnection.customization
Set custlists = cust.Lists
Set custlist = cutslists.List

Set custlist = custlists.List("Bug Status")  'it is listing complete bug status values not specific 'to the project
Set listrootnode = custlist.RootNode
Set listchildren = listrootnode.Children
For Each listname In listchildren
MsgBox (listname.Name)   'Assigned, deferred, cancel...... all are displayed
Next
```

But here i need to replace Bug_status with something related to Detected in cycle field. So i need help in finding out this name of custom list....

Comment: Can anybody plz answer my Question??

Answer (score 1):

i was able to get list of cycles avaiable in QC project. Here is the code:

Set cycles = UserForm9.QCConnection.CycleFactory ' here CycleFactory, a method in QC API will help ' you get complete list

So Bug status is a customization list.

And Cycles is not customized list but could be extracted by CycleFacotry method.